# Householder reflection

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $\tau \in \mathbb C$, $x,y,v \in \mathbb C^n$.

I have to show that if

i) $|\tau| =\frac{ \|x \|_2}{\|y\|_2}$,

ii) $\tau x^H y \in \mathbb R $

iii)  $ \rho( x-\tau y)=v$ with $|p|=\frac{1}{\|x-\tau y\|_2}$,

then $\|v\|_2=1$ and $(I-2v^Hv)x=\tau y$.

I raelly don't know how to use ii), any hint ?

Comment: I believe the equation you have for the reflector is incorrect, it should be $I - 2vv^H$. I tried editing this on your post but it was shot down from some strange reason. Please consider making this change.

Answer (score 0):

That $\|v\| =1$ follows directly from (iii). To prove that $(I -2vv^H)x = \tau y$ it is enough to show that $2p(v^Hx)=1$. Hint: from (ii) it follows that

$$
\tau x^Hy = \overline{\tau x^Hy} = \bar{\tau}\overline{x^Hy}=\bar{\tau}y^Hx
$$